# How to make simple android app with roboguice that injects a textView?

Tags: android, roboguice

I'm a beginner in dependency injection and roboguice. I just want to be able to inject views and resources in my app. The problem is, I get a ClassNotFoundException when I extend my class with RoboActivity.

```
package tes.tes;
//imports
public class test extends RoboActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
  06-09 13:54:08.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(495): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{tes.tes/tes.tes.test}:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tes.tes.test in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/tes.tes-1.apk]
  06-09 13:54:08.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(495):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
  06-09 13:54:08.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(495):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
...
  06-09 13:54:08.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(495): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tes.tes.test in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/tes.tes-1.apk]
  06-09 13:54:08.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(495):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243
...
```

and my manifest

```
coding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="tes.tes"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".test"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I think my dependencies are fine since I can see the jar files for guice, roboguice, etc..
I tried following the documentation and downloading the sample code but it was too complicated for me.
I don't know what I'm missing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your classpath (`tes.tes.test`) looks fishy. Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` .

Comment: I've posted my manifest. Thank you for the fast reply!

Comment: I guess I should have asked for the package of the `test` class as well! My bad. So, what's the `test` class' package name?

Comment: its okay.. ive updated it.. is there anything else you need to help me?

Comment: Your package naming convention is really poor. Consider using standard conventions ( http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm )

Comment: Thank you for the link! I'll make sure I'll hit that next time..

Answer (score 1):

I'm submitting a new answer because RoboGuice 2.0 has changed the way this works. Now, create an XML file in res/values/ named roboguice.xml. List your modules there, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources> 
    <string-array name="roboguice_modules">
    <item>com.example.CustomRenderModule</item>
    <item>com.you.yourmodule.TexModule</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

[Another example.](https://github.com/charlesmunger/OpenGLDemo/blob/master/res/values/roboguice.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly extending RoboApplication. Please consider going through the complete [RoboGuice installation tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Installation)

Comment: have you successfully used roboguice? Thanks, I was worried something else was causing the problem..

Comment: I've used RoboGuice with two major projects. I'd recommend watching the following Google Guice video before diving into RoboGuice:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBVJbzAagfs&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 0):

I followed the manual and used proper naming conventions and it worked!

although this line

```
@Override
protected void addApplicationModules(List<Module> modules) {
    modules.add(new MyModule());
}
```

in MyApplication.java which extends RoboApplication has errors and says remove @Override and when I remove the @Override it says it clashes with another method located in RoboApplication. I dont know why.

Comment: This is a common gotcha when using roboguice 1.1.  Thankfully, the upcoming roboguice 1.2 should make this step superfluous.